# Actionscript 3: Increment a variable (++1)

Tags: actionscript-3, increment

The problem is in the addition of `i`. I have tried `++i`, I have tried `i=i+1` as well as `i.tostring()` and `i++` but I still get the output as

> hitting!1

How do I increment `i`?

Here's my code:

```
function mousePosition(inputEvent:MouseEvent)
{
    var i:Number = 0;
    var smiley:MovieClip = new Smiley();
    smiley.x = inputEvent.stageX;
    smiley.y = inputEvent.stageY;
    smiley.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, smileyEnterFrame, false, 0, true);
    this.addChild(smiley);
    // ****************************** BELOW IS THE PROBLEM ******
        if (smiley.hitTestObject(RoundButton1) == true)
    {i=i+1;
        trace("hitting!"+ i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable `i` only has scope within your `mousePosition` function, so each time you call `mousePosition` you are declaring a new `i` and setting it to `0`. Try declaring your `hitCounter` variable outside of the function, so that it has a global scope.

```
var hitCounter:Number = 0;

function mousePosition(inputEvent:MouseEvent)
{
   ...
   if (smiley.hitTestObject(RoundButton1) == true)
   {
       hitCounter++;
       trace('hitting! ' + hitCounter);
   }
}
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: Ah scope! This is what I get for learning in the night instead of sleeping! Thanks! :)

Comment: Coding at night will do that...I still haven't learned my lesson. ;)

Comment: Heh! Tell me about it! I code in other languages like Java or web programming using PHP... and still break the golden rule of "just finishing this part then go to sleep" :D